# How to extract specific numbers based on the conditions in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a bunch of lines created by connecting some points. I have the number number of lines as a numpy array:

```
line_no_A= np.arange (17, 31)
sep_A=23
```

These lines are arranged in two perpendicular direction, shown as blue and red lines. From the `sep`, direction of lines changes.
I have also the number of points createing these lines:

```
point_rep_A=np.array([4, 3, 3, 1])
```

Now, I want to extract some specific lines. I uploaded a fig and shown the specifics line with blue circles. To find the red lines with circle in scenario_A, I can firstly check the `point_rep_A`: first value is 4 and second is 3, makes 1 difference: so, from the first `point_rep_A[0] - 1` red lines, keep the first one (line number `24` out of `24`, `25` and `26`). Then, the diff between `point_rep_A[1] - point_rep_A[2]` is zero, so from the `point_rep_A[1] - 1` red lines, keep none of them. Then, `point_rep_A[2] - point_rep_A[3]` equals 2, so keep the first two lines (`29` and `30`). For the `point_rep_A[4]`, if it is 1, it means ther is only one point and can not make any red line. But, if it is bigger than one, I want to keep all lines out of `point_rep_A[4] - 1` red lines.
for specific böue lines, `point_rep_A[1] - point_rep_A[2]` is not zero, so I want to keep the first lines of the next follwong chunkcs of blue line. I mean first line of `point_rep_A[1] - 1` blue lines (which is `17` out of `17`, `18` and `19`). First line of `point_rep_A[2] - 1` blue lines (which is `20` out of `20`, `21` and `22`). And finally First line of `point_rep_A[3] - 1` blue lines (which is `23` out of `23`). In fact, I want to start picking these lines just after the first change in `point_rep_A` happens. I think my fig can show the idea better. Finally I want to have such result:

```
[24, 17, 20, 29, 30, 23]
```

For scenario B, my specific lines are the last ones of each chunk. Here I want all blue lines of each chunk but in previous one I wanted to start picking them after the first change in `point_rep_A`.  My input for scenario B is:

```
line_no_B= np.arange (17, 34)
sep_B=25
point_rep_B=np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

I want to have such result for scenarion B:

```
[17, 26, 19, 28, 22, 25, 33]
```

I do appreciate if any one help me to an algorithm for my idea in python. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: "for specific blue lines, `point_rep_A[1] - point_rep_A[2]` is not zero". Well, according to your own definition of `point_rep_A`, `point_rep_A[1] - point_rep_A[2]` **is** zero. You have to express more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Dear @DavidM., for blue line, I want to find where the values of `point_rep_A` changes: it changes in the second value (first one is `4` and second is `3`). So, I want to pick first values of the following chunks: first of `17`, `18` and `19`, first of `20`, `21` and `22`, first of `23`. If for example the change was in the third value of `point_rep_A`, then I wanted to only pick first value of `20`, `21` and `22`, first of `23`. In fact, I want to strart picking first values after the first change in `point_rep_A`.

Comment: So what you mean is that `point_rep_A[0] - point_rep_A[1]` is not zero?

Comment: Dear @David M, Exactly, I want to strat the process of picking blue lines after the change. To visualize it, Lets think in scenario A we do not have the the red line numbered `24`. Then, I did not need blue lines numbered `17` and `20` and I only needed the blue line numbered `23`.

Comment: I have tackled Scenario A. Please let me know if this solution satisfies your objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first part:

```
# SCENARIO A

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

# Input data
line_no_A = np.arange(17, 31)
sep_A = 23
point_rep_A = np.array([4, 3, 3, 1])

# RED LINES

# Red candidates
point_rep_red = point_rep_A - 1
red_A = line_no_A[np.where(line_no_A == sep_A)[0][0]+1:]

# Build red array
red_array = np.zeros(shape=(3, 4))
red_lines_index = np.cumsum(point_rep_red)
red_lines_index = np.insert(red_lines_index, 0, 0)
for i in range(len(red_lines_index)-1):
    red_array[:,i][:point_rep_red[i]] = red_A[red_lines_index[i]:red_lines_index[i + 1]][::-1]

# Select red lines
shift_rep_A = point_rep_red - shift(point_rep_red, -1, cval=0)
red_specific = [red_array[:, i][:point_rep_red[i]][red_array[:, i][:point_rep_red[i]].size-ind:][::-1] for i, ind in enumerate(shift_rep_A)]
red_specific = np.array(red_specific, dtype=object)

# BLUE LINES

# Blue candidates
blue_A = line_no_A[:np.where(line_no_A == sep_A)[0][0]+1]

# Build blue array
blue_array = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
blue_lines_index = np.cumsum(point_rep_A[1:])
blue_lines_index = np.insert(blue_lines_index, 0, 0)
for i in range(len(blue_lines_index)-1):
    blue_array[:,i][:point_rep_A[i+1]] = blue_A[blue_lines_index[i]:blue_lines_index[i + 1]][::-1]

# Select blue lines
first_change_index = np.argmax(shift_rep_A > 0)  # index of first change in point_rep_A
blue_specific = np.array([blue_array[point_rep_A[i+1]-1, i] for i in range(blue_array.shape[1])])
blue_specific[:first_change_index] = np.nan  # skip values before the first change in point_rep_A
blue_specific = np.append(blue_specific, np.nan)  # make it the same length as red_specific
blue_specific = np.array(blue_specific, dtype=object)

# Merge red lines and blue lines
result_A = np.hstack(np.ravel(np.column_stack((red_specific, blue_specific))))
result_A = result_A[~np.isnan(result_A)]  # remove NaNs
print(result_A)
```

And the output is:

```
[24. 17. 20. 29. 30. 23.]
```