# how to create lines and surfaces using points of a regular grid in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a bunch of points and want to do some geometrical processes on them. Points create a regular grid including vertical (red) and horizontal (blue) lines (a fig is uploaded). I want to work with the number and also coordinate (`x,y,z`) of the points. For example, points numbers and coordinate in scenario A of my fig are:

```
point_no= np.arange (1,9)
point_A_coordinate=np.array([[0,0,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,2], [1,0,1], [1,1,3], [2,0,1], [2,1,1], [3,0,1]]
```

I have the number of points in each column (I mean the red lines) (shown in red circle in fig). In scenario A it is:

```
chunk_val_A=np.array([3, 2, 2, 1])
```

When `chunk_val_A[0]` is 3, it means I have 2 red lines in that chunk. First one is created by connecting point 1 to 2 and the second line by point 2 to 3. Then, my algorithm should know that point number 3 must not be connected to 4 because chunk_val_A[0] is 3. In next chunk, I start by connecting 4 to 5 and stop at 5 because `chunk_val_A[0] + chunk_val_A[1]` equals 5. As output I want to have the point numbers that create red line as pairs:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

For blue (lines that connect chunks) lines it is a little bit complicated. About number of connecting lines from chunk `i` to chunk `i+1`, if the `chunk_val` array is descending (scenarios A and C), it equals `chunk_val_A[i+1]`, if it is ascending (scenarios B and D) it equals `chunk_val_A[i]`. But in scenario E I have both ascending and descending and I want to regard the rule until where it is ascending and then change it from where it starts to be descending. I may have some peaks but I want to keep the rule the same as before. To select which pairs create blue lines, if the values of `chunk_val[i]` and `chunk_val[i+1]` be the same, just simply pair the first ones of each chunk, then, seconds and so on (like in scenario A I pair point numbers 4-6 and 8-7 to connect the second and third chunks). In other cases (like first and second chunks of all scenarios), I should check the coordinate. In scenario A, second chunk has point less than first one and If I check `x` and `y` of points `point_A_coordinate[:,0:2]`, missing point is the last point (it's `x` and `y` should be 1 and 2) of the second chunk. So two connecting lines will start from the lower part of the first chunk. In scenario B from first to second chunk, the first one misses the lower point so the only line get connected with upper point of the second chunk. Finally I want to have such pairs for the blue lines of scenario A:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8)]
```

after creating such lines, I want to use them for making surfaces. If the algorithm can make firstly re line and number them and later blue ones, I think it will be possible to find out where these lines can be paired. In scenario A I have shown line numbers in rectangle. I want to have these pairs to create surfaces in scenario A:

```
[(1, 5, 3, 6), (3, 7, 4, 8)]
```

As the final issue, I want to extract the number of lines that are close to the dashed red line. In scenario A, they are (I marked them by a cross in all scenarios):

```
[(2, 6, 8, 4, 9)]
```

These are the things I want to do in Python. I do appreciate if anyone help me in any step of it. I do appreciate any help for such a long issue. Thanks in advance.
I tried the following code for creating lines but it was not successful for all the case (I just used print function to show the pairs):

```
cord_A=np.array([[0,0,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,2], [1,0,1], [1,1,3], [2,0,1], [2,1,1], [3,0,1]])
cord_B=np.array([[0,2,2], [1,1,3], [1,2,2], [2,1,1], [2,2,3], [3,0,1], [3,1,1], [3,2,1]])
cord_C=np.array([[0,0,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,2], [1,1,1], [1,2,3], [2,1,1], [2,2,1], [3,2,1]])
cord_D=np.array([[0,0,2], [1,0,3], [1,1,2], [2,0,1], [2,1,3], [3,0,1], [3,1,1], [3,2,1]])

chunk_val_A=np.array([3, 2, 2, 1])
chunk_val_C=np.array([3, 2, 2, 1])
chunk_val_B=np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])
chunk_val_D=np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])

cord=np.array([[0,0,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,2], [1,0,1], [1,1,3], [2,0,1], [2,1,1], [3,0,1]]) # each time use one scenario
chunk_val=np.array([3, 2, 2, 1]) # again from the same scenario
summ=np.cumsum(chunk_val)
countinuous_point=np.arange(1,9)
splited_point=np.split(countinuous_point,np.cumsum(chunk_val))[:-1]
for i in countinuous_point:
    if i in summ:
        continue
    print (i, i+1) # it gives red lines
print ('All')
for j in range (len (chunk_val)-1):
    if chunk_val[j]==chunk_val[j+1]:
        for m, n in zip (splited_point[j], splited_point[j+1]):
            print (m, n) # it gives the blue lines when the chunks have the same length
    else:
        if cord[splited_point[j][-1]-1,1] > cord[splited_point[j+1][-1]-1,1]:
            for h, p in zip (splited_point[j], splited_point[j+1]):
                print (h,p) # it gives the blue lines when the chunks are like scenario A
        if cord[splited_point[j][-1],1] > cord[splited_point[j+1][0],1]:
            for h, p in zip (splited_point[j][1:], splited_point[j+1]):
                print (h,p) # it gives the blue lines when the chunks are like scenario B               
        if cord[splited_point[j][0],1] < cord[splited_point[j+1][0],1]:
            for h, p in zip (splited_point[j][1:], splited_point[j+1]):
                print (h,p) # it gives the blue lines when the chunks are like scenario C
        if cord[splited_point[j][-1],1] < cord[splited_point[j+1][-1],1]:
            for h, p in zip (splited_point[j][1:], splited_point[j+1]):
                print (h,p) # it gives the blue lines when the chunks are like scenario D
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `[(1, 5, 6, 6), (3, 7, 4, 8)] ` be `[(1, 5, 3, 6), (3, 7, 4, 8)]` instead?

Comment: Dear @ wuerfelfreak, you are exactly right.

Comment: I have multiple questions: Do you only need the solution for these 5 specific cases or for arbitrary cases? Do you also need to know where the lines go or is it ok if the algorithm directly outputs the marked surfaces? Where do the dashed-red-lines come from, is there a rule where they are?

Comment: Dear @ wuerfelfreak, these cases show the distribution of my points. The number points changes but the distribution will be one of these. I only want numbers of lines, e.g. which lines numbers create the first surfaces and second ans so on. Like the numbered lines, in scenario A, I do not care where the line is, I just care about its number. The dashed lines can be detected by the jagged surfaces. Consider a bigger grid having several surfaces, then cut this grid by line, you will lose some surfaces in the adjancey of the cutting line. Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives would be my solution to extracting the surfaces.
I hope this helps you. Did not implement a solution for finding the edges close to the red dashed line though.

```
import numpy as np

point_no= np.arange (1,9)
point_A_coordinate=np.array([[0,0,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,2], [1,0,1], [1,1,3], [2,0,1], [2,1,1], [3,0,1]])
chunk_val_A=np.array([3, 2, 2, 1])

max_x = max([x for x,y,z in point_A_coordinate])
max_y = max([y for x,y,z in point_A_coordinate])

points = np.full((max_x+1,max_y+1), -1) # Grid for storing points -1 marks that there is no point.
red_lines = []
blue_lines = []
n = 0
for chunk, chunk_val in enumerate(chunk_val_A):
    for i in range(chunk_val):
        points[chunk,i] = 1 # 1 markes that there is a point
        n += 1
        if i > 0 and points[chunk,i-1] >= 0: red_lines.append( ((chunk,i-1), (chunk,i)) ) #adds red lines
        if chunk > 0 and points[chunk-1,i] >= 0: blue_lines.append(((chunk-1, i), (chunk,i))) # adds blue lines

print(points) # contains all your points like you would draw them on the paper. -1=no point . otherwise points z-kordinate
print(red_lines) # contains all red lines but named by there x,y cord-pairs
print(blue_lines) # contains all blue lines but named by there x,y cord-pairs

#surfaces
surfaces = []
for x in range(max_x):
    for y in range(max_y):
        if( points[x,y] >= 0 and # checks if all for points exist
            points[x+1,y] >= 0 and
            points[x,y+1] >= 0 and
            points[x+1,y+1] >= 0):
                surfaces.append((
                    red_lines.index( ((x,y), (x,y+1)) ) +1, # gets the number of each line and adds it to the surface
                    blue_lines.index(((x, y), (x + 1, y))) + len(red_lines) + 1,
                    red_lines.index(((x + 1, y), (x + 1, y + 1))) + 1,
                    blue_lines.index( ((x, y+1), (x+1, y+1))) + len(red_lines) + 1,
                ))

print(surfaces) # contains all surfaces

red_lines_numbers = [red_lines.index( red_line ) +1 for red_line in red_lines] 
blue_lines_numbers = [blue_lines.index( blue_line ) + len(red_lines) +1 for blue_line in blue_lines]

red_lines_points_numbers = [(
        [ i for i,cords in enumerate(point_A_coordinate) if all(cords[:2] == red_line[0])][0]+1,
        [ i for i,cords in enumerate(point_A_coordinate) if all(cords[:2] == red_line[1])][0]+1
    ) for red_line in red_lines]

blue_lines_points_numbers = [(
        [ i for i,cords in enumerate(point_A_coordinate) if all(cords[:2] == blue_line[0])][0]+1,
        [ i for i,cords in enumerate(point_A_coordinate) if all(cords[:2] == blue_line[1])][0]+1
    ) for blue_line in blue_lines]
```

You really stepped up the numbering-game. Most code is just for handling your complex numbering. I first converted everything to the respective x,y coordinates and back afterwards because it is way more intuitive to do math with.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, I do appreciate you for devoting time. Unfortunately at the moment I am at home (I am in the europe at it is about 18:00 o’clock) and have no access to my PC and data. Definitely your solution is right, but in the case of having issue with my real data, can I add comments tomorrow? Thanks again for being that much supportive.

Comment: No, problem at all. Similar time here.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, Thanks again for your efficient solution. Is there any way to extract the number of point pairs which create lines rather than their coordinate? I am using a python package for generating mesh. It firstly says which point numbers create lines and then which line numbers create surfaces. It is working mainly with numbers rather than coordinate. Your solution is giving me the Line numbers creating surfaces but I do not have the point numbers to firstly create lines in my python package.

Comment: I added two lines at the end.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, sorry for making that much trouble. I there any way to find out the point numbers creating these lines. For example for red lines it should be: `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Added another 8 lines.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, you solved a gigantic issue for me. I really appreciate it. About the line numbers which are close to dashed line, I previously opend issues in SO for some cases and people really helped me. for example [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509793/how-to-write-an-algorithm-for-finding-specific-values-of-a-numpy-array-in-python]. Do you think such thing can be embedded to your solution ? I really do appreciate you if you take a look at it also. Up to know you helped me a lot. Thanks for being that much supportive.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, is there anyway to modify your method for floats? In cases I have floate numbers rather than int, but still the grid is regular.

Comment: Should already mostly work for floats. Only when indexing you would need to do `[int(float)]`

Comment: When I try it, I have the error in the line `np.full((max_x+1,max_y+1), -1)`. I changed them to int. Then, I also in the line `for x in range(max_x)`, again changed it to int but I faces another error for creating `red_lines_points_numbers`. It says: `list index out of range`. I thought maybe it is because of my float arrays.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, sorry to iterrupt you but unfortunately I could not figure out how to solve the int and float problem.

Comment: Dear @wuerfelfreak, hope doing well. Sorry for interupting you again. I unfortunately have problems when sing your solution for real data. Lets say we have somethin like scenario B: `np.array([[0,4,2], [0,5,3], [1,0,3], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [1,3,1], [1,4,3], [1,5,1], [2,0,1], [2,1,1]])` and `chunk_val_A=np.array([2, 5, 2])`. This arrangement has one surface for high `y` values between first and second chunks and another surface for low `y` values between second and third chunks, But the line numbers are not what I expect: `[(1, 7, 5, 8), (2, 9, 6, 10)]`. The first surface of output is wrong.